# Using SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to change the color of View

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview and want to change View `(@+id/panel)` color, based on some condition that is retrieved from SQLite database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="10dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.01"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

       <View
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#ffa500"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.86"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textViewB"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:text="" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to do that:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){    

    if (view.getId() == R.id.panel) 
    {                               
        String name = cursor.getString(1);

        if (name.equals("Ravi")) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}               

listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(binder);
```

This code still does not work. The code never pass through condition.
I can change font color of TextView object `(@+id/textViewB)`, but never succeeded to change View color.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is there only one row that you want to have different color from the rest? Or several rows? If only one row, I may be able to help.

Comment: Several row depend on condition. But i would like to see your solution for one row too

Comment: Why don't you extend SimpleCursorAdapter and override getView instead.

Comment: Do you actually pass the *panel* `View` when you create the adapter so it knows it has to bind it?

Answer (score 0):

A [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) is

> An easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews or
>   ImageViews defined in an XML file.

I'm not sure to what `View` you are trying to bind the values from the database, but I'm thinking that it only works for the `TextView` object `(@+id/textViewB)` because `TextView` is one of the `View` types that you can use this interface for.

Try using a [SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html) instead? Otherwise using `getView()` will probably give you good results.